# NetBeans "inline variable" refactoring

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring, resharper

Is it possible to inline (and the other way around) variables with a NetBeans refactoring?

Something like this:

```
Something s = new Something();
render(s);
```

should become

```
render(new Something());
```

The ReSharper equivalent is `Ctrl+R+I`.

Comment: I think the correct term for this is "_wrapping_" instead of "_inline_". Inlining can be done in C++.

Comment: Eclipse and IntelliJ call this "inline variable" also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this functionality has been requested and subsequently integrated into 7.1.  The RFE in question is [Bug 57545 - Inline Method/Variable Refactoring](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57545) and according to [comment #17](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57545#c17) has been integrated into `main_golden`.

Also according to [comment #19](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57545#c19) this feature will be included in version 7.1 which is in Beta now ([download here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/7.1/beta/)) and according to the [roadmap](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/roadmap.html) is due to be released on Dec 14, 2011

**Edit**

I downloaded NetBeans 7.1 Beta and successfully refactored your example into your requirement.  To do this, I placed my cursor on the `s` of `Something s = new Something();` and from the context menu (right click) I selected `Inline...`.  This brought up this warning:

[image: Inline refactor warning]

After clicking Preview you get the following diff:

[image: Inline refactor diff view]

After clicking on the `Do Refactoring` button, the refactor is complete.

Comment: Thank you for finding this out.